# Excel pivot table allows me to select variables for slicers that are not available in field list (where I need them to be)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

I've be handed a pivot table with an external connection I don't have access to, so I can't just refresh or redo the table.

There are fields showing up in the slicer list that I need to put as rows on the table but they won't show up on the field list menu. Is it possible to make it show up there without refreshing the cache?